# Customize mapTypeControlOptions with gmaps4rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails

Is it possible to customize how the map options are displayed on the google map?

It seems this is an option in the API using `mapTypeControlOptions` wiht an array of `mapTypeIDs`.

Thanks to *apneadiving* for developing this awesome gem!!!

Comment: This is kind of what I really wanted to achieve:
http://stackoverflow.com/q/11404725/1481208

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add any option google map enables. From the doc [here](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Map-Apis):

> If you lack some options for maps and markers, you can simply pass
>   what you need in :raw:

```
<%= gmaps(:markers => {:data => @json, :options => { :raw => '{ animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE }' } },
          :map_options => { :raw => '{ disableDefaultUI: true, scrollwheel: false }' }) %>
```

Comment: I had tried using the `:raw` option but had the array of `mapTypeIds` wrong. Tried again and got what I wanted like this:
`<%= gmaps("markers" => {"data" => @json},
"map_options" => {"type" => "TERRAIN", :raw => '{mapTypeControlOptions: {mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN]}}'}) %>`

Did you see my other follow-up question at http://stackoverflow.com/q/11404725/1481208 ? This would require creating a new, custom `mapTypeId`. Could this be an option for a future release of your gem? Thanks for you quick answer on this one.